# SQLite-sync Sync Framework in Android app

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, opencv, synchronization

I am working on a project which can sync SQLite on Android app with MySQL on server. At first, my approach is: 
-Create a periodic sync service to sync to MySQL via Restful API 
-Sync algorithm: http://havrl.blogspot.ie/2013/08/synchronization-algorithm-for.html
-Using Retrofit lib: REST client for Android app. 
But I am new to Android and I find it quite difficult to implement this approach. I found another solution: **SQLite-sync Synchronization Framework** - http://wiki.sqlite-sync.com/projects/sqlite-sync-com-synchronization-tool 
This framework is based on Sencha Touch but my project is a native app. 
-**1**: Is there any approaches to use this framework on my project smoothly with the existed SQLite database? 
-**2**: If not, I have to develop sync module from scratch. Is my first approach OK ? 

In additional, I have an OCR function on my project which recognize 7-segment number on 7 segment LCD panel using OpenCV. It recognizes well in virtual environment (black-white PC screen) but in actual environment (blood glucose monitor), it doesn't, because of contrast ratio, I thought. So, how can I improve quality of OpenCV 7-segment number recognition ? (contrast,etc) I have no idea of what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can go by the Sync algorithm you have mentioned in the link - http://havrl.blogspot.ie/2013/08/synchronization-algorithm-for.html

Use Rest APIs within Android sync adapter concept. Highly recommended as it has lot many advantages. Lot of plumbing code can be avoided

Comment: Yes.. I got one point from this blog. Dirty & deleted concept..really useful